# Component is not updating in React

Tags: reactjs

Below is my ract component, why after line `this.setState({ configurableOptions: newConfigurableOptions });` is executed, component is not re-rendered.
1.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import {
    CategoryConfigurableAttributesContainer as SourceCategoryConfigurableAttributesContainer,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    mapStateToProps,
} from 'SourceComponent/CategoryConfigurableAttributes/CategoryConfigurableAttributes.container';

import { CategoryConfigurableAttributesComponentContainerFunctions } from './CategoryConfigurableAttributes.type';

/** @namespace KosmetickaTheme/Component/CategoryConfigurableAttributes/Container */
export class CategoryConfigurableAttributesContainer extends SourceCategoryConfigurableAttributesContainer {
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
        const { configurable_options } = props;

        return {
            configurableOptions: configurable_options,
        };
    }

    containerFunctions: CategoryConfigurableAttributesComponentContainerFunctions = {
        ...this.containerFunctions,
        handleChangeAttributeFilter: this.handleChangeAttributeFilter.bind(this),
    };

    containerProps(): Pick<
    ProductConfigurableAttributesComponentProps,
    ProductConfigurableAttributesComponentContainerPropsKeys
    > {
        const { configurableOptions } = this.state;

        return {
            ...super.containerProps(),
            configurable_options: configurableOptions,
        };
    }

    handleChangeAttributeFilter(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        const { target: { value, dataset: { attribute } } } = event;
        const { configurable_options } = this.props;
        const newAttributeOptions = Object.keys(configurable_options[attribute].attribute_options)
            .filter((key) => configurable_options[attribute].attribute_options[key].label.indexOf(value) !== -1)
            .reduce((result, key) => {
                result[key] = configurable_options[attribute].attribute_options[key];

                return result;
            }, {});
        const newConfigurableOptions = {
            ...this.state.configurableOptions,
            [attribute]: {
                ...this.state.configurableOptions[attribute],
                attribute_options: newAttributeOptions,
                attribute_values: Object.keys(newAttributeOptions),
            },
        };

        this.setState({ configurableOptions: newConfigurableOptions });
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CategoryConfigurableAttributesContainer);
```

Comment: If the handler is invoked as a change event callback you may need to bind it to the class so that `this` refers to your component and not the global scope.

Comment: Could you provide some examples,  I binded on change handler with `.bind(this)`